# Make TvInputService display an overlay

Tags: android-tv

I'm trying to write a most simple TvInputService, that will display an overlay using [TIF Companion Library](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-sample-inputs).

The Live Channels application already recognizes my channel `Simple Channel` declared in my `EpgSyncJobService` subclass.
`My Program` is displayed in the Live Channels application's EPG as currently presented one.
However, all I can see is the blue spinner, as if the channel didn't "tune".

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MyTvInputService extends BaseTvInputService {
        @Override
    public final BaseTvInputService.Session onCreateSession(String inputId) {
        BaseTvInputService.Session session = new MyTvInputSession(this, inputId);
        session.setOverlayViewEnabled(true);
        return super.sessionCreated(session);
    }

    class MyTvInputSession extends BaseTvInputService.Session {
        public MyTvInputSession(Context context, String inputId) {
            super(context, inputId);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateOverlayView() {
            mTextView = new TextView(MyTvInputService.this);
            mTextView.setText("This is an example overlay");
            mTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mTextView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            return mTextView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPlayProgram(Program program, long startPosMs) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPlayRecordedProgram(RecordedProgram recordedProgram) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSetCaptionEnabled(boolean enable) {}

        @Override
        public TvPlayer getTvPlayer() { return null; }
    }
    private TextView mTextView;
}
```

Comment: hello, i'm trying to build a android tv app using TIF, i'm using the documentation on https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/tvinput as a guide, i kind of have 2 problems, 1) service is not binding automatically and 2) session is never created even when i have the android tv connected with HDMI and HDMI CEC is enabled, any clue what i might do wrong?

Comment: It's tricky in many ways. Please make sure you've given your service  android.permission.BIND_TV_INPUT android:permission, and a proper intent-filter.

Another common issue broken TV App implementation on some devices. Please try using google.android.permission.BIND_TV_INPUT (notice the google prefix).

You should also try it out on the emulator first. It's the least broken platform.

I'm glad to help if you open an SO question.

Comment: i found out the service was not binding automatically because that services is only binding when live channels app is opened, but this app is to work all over the app, not over the Live Channels app, in this case i basically have the 2nd issue left, any clue about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [TvInputService.Session.notifyVideoAvailable() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvInputService.Session.html#notifyVideoAvailable()):

> The TV input service must call this method as soon as the content
>   rendered onto its surface is ready for viewing. This method must be
>   called each time onTune(Uri) is called.

So it is enough to call `notifyVideoAvailable()` in `BaseTvInputService.Session.onTune(Uri)` method override, like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onTune(Uri channelUri) {
    notifyVideoAvailable();
    return true;
}
```

I must say, that using the TV Companion Library's `BaseTvInputService` makes finding such issues harder than when using bare `TvInputService`, as an `onTune()` method is non-abstract in `BaseTvInputService.Session`.